# How to send multidimensional array by jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to send multidimensional array to PHP script.

I have simple script:

```
var data = [{ name: 'test1', value: 'test data' }, { name: 'test2', value: 'test data' }];
  
$.post('script.php', data, function (data) {
    alert('ok');
  },
);
```

But PHP return me:

```
[
  "test1" => "test data"
  "test2" => "test data"
]
```

I would like to receive:

```
[
  {'name': 'test1', 'value': 'test data'},
  {'name': 'test2', 'value': 'test data'}
]
```

How can I make it?

Comment: If you want PHP to send you something different, I think you might need to look at the PHP code...not the JavaScript.

Comment: POST parameters are always in the format name=value. You can't send a value without a name.

Comment: What are you expecting the key in `$_POST` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to JSON to send it in the format you want:

```
$.post("script.php", {data: JSON.stringify(data)}, function ...);
```

Then decode it in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```